# ASP.NET Chart Control - how to autoplot chart area with empty?

Tags: asp.net, database, charts

It might seem strange that I want to plot my graph with empty series.

But here's the deal. My chart is plotting data from the database between 2 dates, that is provided to a stored procedure.

A result like this:

```
2011-08-05 - 37,5
2011-08-11 - 20,1
2011-08-16 - 8,0
2011-08-17 - 15,7
```

The x-axis is plotted with the dates. And the y-axis is plotted with the numbers (decimals).

There's no problem plotting them.

But I want it like this:

```
2011-08-01 - 0
2011-08-02 - 0
^
etc.
v
2011-08-05 - 37,5
2011-08-06 - 20,1
2011-08-07 - 8,0
2011-08-08 - 15,7
^
etc.
v
2011-08-30 - 0
2011-08-31 - 0
```

**Can anyone give me a hint?**

My code looks like this:

```
        <asp:Chart ID="Chart_NormalRegistrations" runat="server" Height="650px" Width="975px" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Palette="Bright">
            <Series>
                <asp:Series Name="Series1" XValueMember="Dato" XValueType="DateTime" ChartArea="" 
                    YValueMembers="Total" YValueType="Double" YValuesPerPoint="1">
                </asp:Series>
            </Series>
            <ChartAreas>
                <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
                    <AxisY Title="Tid" Interval="5">
                    </AxisY>
                    <AxisX Title="Dage" Interval="1">
                    </AxisX>
                    <Area3DStyle Enable3D="True" />
                </asp:ChartArea>
            </ChartAreas>
        </asp:Chart>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString=" //connectionstring" 
            SelectCommand="stored_proc_regs" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="2011-08-01" Name="from" Type="DateTime" />
                <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="2011-09-01" Name="to" Type="DateTime" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: To clarify even further it would mean I want a pre-plotted X-axis with dates ranging from 1st to last in the month specified. It should however, still plot data into the x-axis on the dates with data ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
<AxisX Title="Dage" Interval="1">
```

In this tag, you can set an explicit [Minimum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.axis.minimum.aspx) and [Maximum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.axis.maximum.aspx) for the axis, and the chart will respect them. But working out what to set might be a bit tricky.

Assuming your stored proc is returning `DateTime`s (or sql equivalent), the chart will effectively be converting these to `double`s using the [OLE Automation conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2k67kb6.aspx), which is near enough the number of days after midnight 30 December 1899. If you are (as it looks) just using markup, you will have to compute this manually for the dates you want and supply those numbers, as I don't think the chart markup will convert for you.

The OADate for `2011-08-01` is `40756`, and to add a day just add `1`, so the 31st is `40786`. Try that and see if it works - if it does, you can think about if you want to make it easier to specify this, by starting to do some work in code-behind.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) You gave me an idea to try and let the Stored Procedure find all the dates between the two input values, and left join them with the actual data found.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution to this is to inserting empty points to the chart. You will need to use [DataManipulator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.datamanipulator.aspx) Class. Still need to set the x axis max min values as well though.
for example:

```
Chart_NormalRegistration.Series["Series1"]["EmptyPointValue"] = 0;

Chart_NormalRegistration.DataManipulator.InsertEmptyPoints(1, IntervalType.Days, 
            1, IntervalType.Days, "Series1");
```